# Java GregorianCalendar and DST Cutover Times

Tags: java, time, calendar

I have a GregorianCalendar that I am am trying to set the time on.  I am getting the date from one calendar and the time from another calendar.  It mostly works, except for the 2AM hour of the DST switch day.

For example, with a date of 3/10/2013, a time of 2:40AM and a target output of 3/10/2013 2:40AM, I get 3/10/2013 3:40AM:

```
GregorianCalendar reportingDate = //some instance with a relevant date (in this case 3/10/2013)
GregorianCalendar targetTime = //some instance with a relevant time (in this case 2:40AM)
Calendar combination = Calendar.getInstance();
combination.set(Calendar.YEAR, reportingDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
combination.set(Calendar.MONTH, reportingDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
combination.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, reportingDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
combination.set(Calendar.HOUR, targetTime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
combination.set(Calendar.AM_PM, targetTime.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
combination.set(Calendar.MINUTE, targetTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
combination.set(Calendar.SECOND, targetTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

As soon as the code sets the AM_PM on the combination Calendar the time switches to 3:40AM.  I would like it to not switch.  I think this has to do with the target time Calendar being created as a time on the epoch date, but I would like the target time's specific date to not really matter...

Comment: I faced a similar problem and this is because the time zone of your PC doesn't support the 2:00 a.m. on the date when applies the change from standard time to daylight saving time (DST), e.g. (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada). I even tried using joda library without success (maybe I didn't put enough effort). I would like to get an answer on this topic too.

Comment: A couple years on, I've made my peace with the answer that 'this is just how time works'  

You lose an hour.  It is what it is.  Very, very confusing to my users, but some explanation and they are on the same page.  More argument for getting rid of daylight savings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this output... I would think this is just how Java deals with DST?  Seems like 2-3 AM   goes into oblivion

**See my comment below**

```
final Calendar reportingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
reportingDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
reportingDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
reportingDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);

final Calendar targetTime = Calendar.getInstance();
targetTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
targetTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
targetTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
targetTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
targetTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

final Calendar combination = Calendar.getInstance();
combination.set(Calendar.YEAR, reportingDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
combination.set(Calendar.MONTH, reportingDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
combination.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, reportingDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
combination.set(Calendar.HOUR, targetTime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
combination.set(Calendar.AM_PM, targetTime.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
combination.set(Calendar.MINUTE, targetTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
combination.set(Calendar.SECOND, targetTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
combination.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, targetTime.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

final long timeAtCombined = combination.getTimeInMillis();

final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));

// subtract one minute
System.out.println(sdf.format(combination.getTime()));
combination.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(combination.getTime()));

// millis @ 3
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(timeAtCombined)));
// millis @ 3 - 1ms
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(timeAtCombined - 1)));
```

Output

```
03/10/2013 03:00:00.000-0400
03/10/2013 01:59:59.999-0500
03/10/2013 03:00:00.000-0400
03/10/2013 01:59:59.999-0500
```

Comment: Actually, I just noticed where "oblivion" is.. of course, the offset changes at that time.  Java considers the offset to change from 0400 to 0500 at 2-3 AM (this is for EST), so no time is lost, but you cannot represent 3/10/2013 2AM EST with a 0400 offset, because it doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You're setting everything, except for the time zone (which contains the DST). Set that as well, and you should be okay.

Comment: It is what was the solution when I was faced with a similar problem. I am very sorry.

Comment: It is not a solution because when you use `combination.getTime()` it will return a new `Date` object with the pc/server time zone applied, so the time zone change made on the calendar won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question directly but you can avoid all of this craziness by going with [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

They have really nailed the date/time/calendar thing down.

Comment: If you post an example, it would be great.